# how to verify bank account if its valid to receive funds?

Tags: php, onlinebanking

Good day,

I'm currently developing a system for ads, and we have users who advertise / share a post on our site then they get paid for it.

also we have a form that requires their account number. My question is, how do we verify if the account number they write on our form if its valid or not, before we transfer the fund to it? is there a way we can do this electronically? we are currently new to TD's EFT.

I just would like to asks for advice to those who has experienced working with any banking api.

please give me some advice on where to start. Thanks!

Comment: I'd say it's the user's responsibility to give you the correct details. Even if you could validate it's a _real_ bank account, how can you be sure it's the _right_ bank account? Never. In a way it's not really your problem. If they want to get paid they have to tell you accurately where to send the cash. Write a disclaimer to that effect in your terms and conditions. It's a legal issue not a coding issue.

Comment: Surely the API that you are using (which you haven't named in your question) will throw an error if you pass it invalid data?

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight @ADyson ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look at the ISO9362 standard which define the SWIFT code, there is one also for BIC and IBAN codes, so at least you can formally validate the code and find if the user entered a wrong number ( a type error for example).

Once you have a formally valid code, you can eventually check with the correct bank if the api it expose a method to allow it.

But you can neven be sure of the person/account number match until the bank say it.

Comment: Okay @Gianluca .. Thanks for the advice, I think its the best we could do, except for calling the actual bank manually which I think is not very efficient but the only way we could get a correct result..